# TextBox vertical scroll bar not working when applying IsHitTestVisible = False

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, border

I have below TextBox which behaves as a TextBlock using an Sytle:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<TextBox Grid.Column="1"
     BorderBrush="DarkRed"
     BorderThickness="1"
     Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
     x:Name="MyTextBox"
     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
     Height="auto"
     Margin="5"
     Text="{Binding Path=Text}"
     Foreground="{Binding Path=ForegroundColor}">
</TextBox>
```

The problem with this approach is that TextBox content can be selected and I don't want this so in the Style I have added a new property which is below:

```
<Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
```

so now TextBox content cannot be selected. Okay, this is just what I want but now a new side effect is introduced. Now when verticall scroll bar is visible, it is in readonly mode, I cannot click on the up and down buttons of the vertical scroll bar. When I click on them, click is ignored, nothing happens.... so How can I do TextBox content not selectable and at the same time make the vertical scroll bar to work when I click on up and down buttons?

Comment: Can you wrap the TextBox in a ScrollViewer?

Comment: @IlanKeshet You mean using ScrollViewer instead of VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" property? like below: <ScrollViewer><TextBox></TextBox></ScrollViewer>?

Comment: You call your style "TextBlockStyle" but you use a `TextBox`.  Why not just use a `TextBlock` instead?

Comment: @Rodri Yes -- but I'm not sure that will actually work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the textbox's VerticalScrollBarVisibility, try setting ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility attached property on the textbox.